# Salesforce Winter 18 force:createRecord issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In Winter 18 (Sanbox),

I noticed that the force:createRecord event is considering overriden action (Visualforce page) also DefaultFieldValues param is not working for Lead Object and it worked for others like Account.

Does any one encountered same issue?

Thanks
Balaji

Comment: I did not understand - what exactly is the issue?

Comment: The createRecord Event is not opening the standard page. It opens the VF page that was overridden for the new button

Comment: According to the [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm) `it doesn’t respect overrides on the object’s create action` - so you have a problem , maybe this is a bug

Comment: This is a valid question. I am also facing this issue. force:createRecord is working till summer 17 and from winter 18 it is considering overridden action.

Comment: This is a known issue. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EFOoQAO&title=when-attempting-to-create-a-new-record-after-firing-the-force-createrecord-event-the-page-will-go-in-a-loop

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EFOoQAO&title=when-attempting-to-create-a-new-record-after-firing-the-force-createrecord-event-the-page-will-go-in-a-loop) is a Winter 18 known issue. This issue is fixed in most of the data centers. Release is inprogress as of 15th Sept 6PM IST.  Check [this](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EFOoQAO&title=when-attempting-to-create-a-new-record-after-firing-the-force-createrecord-event-the-page-will-go-in-a-loop) link for more.

Comment: It is fixed on my server.